# How does nodetool garbagecollect work on multiple data folders?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool, tombstone

How nodetool garbagecollect removes the shadowed data from the SStable of data0 folder when the tombstone is present in the SStable of data1 folder.

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

JBOD configurations (multiple data directories) do not come into play with the `garbagecollect` command because partitions do not span across directories.

Another way of saying it is that the token ranges are mapped to specific disks so fragments of a partition (which hashes into a token value) will only ever be stored on the same disk. Cheers!